# ObjectReference underlying object in JDI and JPDA

Tags: java, jdi, jpda

Very specifically, in JDI and [JPDA](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/index.html) context, I have the following questions:

- Why `ObjectReference` does not expose its underlying object? Is it based on some specification? Are all implementations such as Eclipse Debug Project the same that do not expose the underlying object?
- Considering the situation that you have the `uniqueID()` from `ObjectReference`, is there any way to resolve the underlying object from **JVM**?
- If no to the previous question, then what is the best way to resolve the underlying object? I should add that I am familiar with how `Value`'s can be obtained from `StackFrame` information, but I really need ***the object reference*** not the internal values or structure of the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why ObjectReference does not expose its underlying object?

I am assuming that you are referring to the `com.sun.jdi.ObjectReference` interface.  If so, it is a combination of two things:

- On the face of it, it wouldn't make sense.  The ObjectReference is in the JVM running the debugger, but the corresponding Java object exists on the target machine.
- Assuming that it did make sense, then it would be a bad thing to expose the actual pbject addresses and memory contents.  This would allow the debugger to do things to the target JVM that would lead to hard crashes.

> Considering the situation that you have the uniqueID() from ObjectReference, is there any way to resolve the underlying object from JVM?

No.

> If no to the previous question, then what is the best way to resolve the underlying object?

AFAIK, there is no way to do this, apart from writing your own debug agent in C / C++ using the JVM Tool Interface and configuring the target JVM to run it.

Comment: It was a very good point that actually we're dealing with ObjectReference in one JVM and Object in another. Thanks.